# Difficulty using SymPy to rearrange formula

Tags: python, sympy

I am looking to rearrange the equation below to solve for 'meters_per_sec':

`Velocity_CoM = meters_per_sec*(Radius-(Lm*math.atan((meters_per_sec**2/(Track_Length/(2*math.pi)))/Gravity)))/Radius`

I have been trying to use SymPy but have had no luck.

Is SymPy able to do this? Any help on what the code would look like would be great Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the expression is too complex for sympy to solve for 'meters_per_sec'.  Also note that you can't work with `math.atan` nor with `math.pi`. You need sympy's equivalents.

Comment: The equation is transcendental and it is unlikely that it can be rearranged. At best there might be a way using Lambert W but I wouldn't expect any CAS to be able to solve this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help @JohanC. This has helped me learn more about how to utilise the sympy library.